# override struct fields in GoLang

Tags: go

I am attempting to override the password field for update validation don't want to check password.
I used Embedded Struct. However, when I apply the validation on update, it returns an error indicating that the password is required.

Here's the relevant code:
***my structs***

```
type User struct {
    ID       uint   `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
    Name     string `json:"name" validate:"required,min=6,max=50"`
    Username string `json:"username" validate:"required,min=6,max=20"`
    Password string `json:"password" validate:"required,min=6,max=20"`
    Role     string `json:"role" validate:"required,oneof=admin"`
}

type UserUpdate struct {
    User
    Password string `json:"password,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=6,max=20"`
}
```

**Controller (using Fiber):**

```
var updatedUser models.UserUpdate
err := ParseAndValidate(c, &updatedUser)
```

```
func ParseAndValidate(c *fiber.Ctx, obj interface{}) *ErrorResponse {
    if err := c.BodyParser(obj); err != nil {
        return &ErrorResponse{
            Error:  err,
            Status: fiber.StatusBadRequest,
        }
    }

    if errs := validator.New().Struct(obj); errs != nil {
        var validationErrors = make(map[string]string)
        for _, err := range errs.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
            field := getJSONFieldName(reflect.TypeOf(obj), err.Field())
            message := UserFriendlyErrorMsg(field, err)
            validationErrors[field] = message
        }

        return &ErrorResponse{
            Error:  validationErrors,
            Status: fiber.StatusBadRequest,
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Can someone provide guidance on how to correctly override the password validation for updates?

Answer (score 0):

you have added password field two times, this can be fixed in two ways:

1. Make password field omit empty:

   ```
   type User struct {
       ID       uint   `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
       Name     string `json:"name" validate:"required,min=6,max=50"`
       Username string `json:"username" validate:"required,min=6,max=20"`
       Password string `json:"password" validate:"omitempty,min=6,max=20"`
       Role     string `json:"role" validate:"required,oneof=admin"`
   }
   type UserUpdate struct {
       User
       Password string `json:"password,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=6,max=20"`
   }
   ```
2. Don't create another struct UserUpdate, update using User and Make user.password field omit empty:

   ```
   type User struct {
       ID       uint   `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
       Name     string `json:"name" validate:"required,min=6,max=50"`
       Username string `json:"username" validate:"required,min=6,max=20"`
       Password string `json:"password,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=6,max=20"`
       Role     string `json:"role" validate:"required,oneof=admin"`
   }
   ```
3. Add new field NewPassword in User struct and validate one of password OR newPassword:

```
type User struct {
        ID       uint   `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
        Name     string `json:"name" validate:"required,min=6,max=50"`
        Username string `json:"username" validate:"required,min=6,max=20"`
        Password string `json:"password,omitempty" validate:"required_without_all=NewPassword,omitempty,min=6,max=20"`
        NewPassword string `json:"newPassword,omitempty" validate:"required_without_all=Password,omitempty,min=6,max=20"`
        Role     string `json:"role" validate:"required,oneof=admin"`
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but my purpose is for create is required but for update is not. non of what being specify here is serve that. I guess I will create two struct (UserCreate, UserUpdate). but course they are not ORM model they are just for validation. that's mean for every table I will have three struct (User, UserCreate, UserUpdate)

Comment: @Nordeen please look at 3rd solution, if user is going to be **inserted** then it is forced to have password and if user is going to be **updated** then it is forced to have newPassword, and you should separate validation model(request parse) with ORM model